# How to Copy LatLng ArryList To Another LatLng ArryList

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

**I have 2 LatLng Lists**

```
List<LatLng> PairOfLatLong = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
List<LatLng> FakePairOfLatLong = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

**Adding LatLng Here**

```
            PairOfLatLong.add(pLatLng);
```

**But In Somewhere i want to copy PairOfLatLong in FakePairOfLatLong**

**I try this way but error occur**

```
  FakePairOfLatLong= (ArrayList<LatLng>) PairOfLatLong.clone();
```

Comment: use `.addAll()`

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
List<LatLng> FakePairOfLatLong = new ArrayList<LatLng>(PairOfLatLong);
```

or

```
FakePairOfLatLong.addAll(PairOfLatLong);
```